# Change edgeindex's Order.DESC to Order.ASC

Tags: titan

I have this edge indexing

```
    EdgeLabel elComment = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("comment").make();
    mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(elComment,"elComment",Direction.IN,Order.DESC,time);
```

Now here instead of Order.DESC i want it to be ORDER.ASC. I did this

```
    TitanManagement mgmt = g.getManagementSystem();
    PropertyKey time = mgmt.getPropertyKey("time");

    EdgeLabel elComment = mgmt.makeEdgeLabel("comment").make();
    mgmt.buildEdgeIndex(elComment,"elComment",Direction.IN,Order.ASC,time);
    mgmt.commit();
    g.rollback();

    boolean registered = false;
    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (!registered) {
        Thread.sleep(500L);
        mgmt = g.getManagementSystem();
        TitanGraphIndex idx  = mgmt.getGraphIndex("elComment");
        registered = true;
        for (PropertyKey k : idx.getFieldKeys()) {
            registered &= idx.getIndexStatus(k).equals(SchemaStatus.REGISTERED);
        }
        mgmt.rollback();
    }
    System.out.println("Index REGISTERED in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - before) + " ms");

    String pt = "org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner";
    TitanIndexRepair.cassandraRepair("conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties", "elComment", "", pt);

    mgmt = g.getManagementSystem();
    mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("elComment"), SchemaAction.ENABLE_INDEX);
    mgmt.commit();

    mgmt = g.getManagementSystem();
    mgmt.getGraphIndex("elComment");
    mgmt.rollback();
```

I am getting this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Adding this property for key [system%&%SchemaName] and value [comment] violates a uniqueness constraint [com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.system.BaseKey$1@73471338]
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:120)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.addPropertyInternal(StandardTitanTx.java:679)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.setProperty(StandardTitanTx.java:716)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.addProperty(StandardTitanTx.java:638)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.makeSchemaVertex(StandardTitanTx.java:753)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx.makeEdgeLabel(StandardTitanTx.java:771)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.StandardEdgeLabelMaker.make(StandardEdgeLabelMaker.java:88)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop here, this question was answered in the Aurelius Graphs mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/7eVUT1zEyfY